# Reclaiming a lost Facebook app

Tags: facebook-apps

I am a new member of a team at my company reviving a legacy product that had Facebook integration, and we wish to continue developing the Facebook side of things, but we can't seem to find the credentials for logging into the app, or even who has access to it.

The app we are trying to recover is "HaloMobile". One thing to note though is the app name on posts is no longer a link. Does this mean the app has been disabled somehow?

I'm obviously not asking for credentials. At this point I'm just trying to "find" the app and possibly determine who is currently assigned as the administrator role, or what my options are. If there is an email address associated with the app, perhaps we can send a transfer request to that email?

Comment: Do you have app Id, app Secret ? Or you could check for the App in User's App settings to get the URL to the application which might have the app Id.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena I might be able to find these in the old codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could get retrieve two piece of information from your code-base, which are **App ID** and **App Secret** then you can retrieve the list of roles assigned in app using the following end point,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<App_ID>/roles?access_token=<App_ID>|<App_Secret>
```

And once you know the role, along with the user Ids of the user assigned to it, you can move forward to recover the App by contacting him.
Also, you might want to give this documentation about [Application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) a look, which lists out various fields you can retrieve for getting the required information to get access to your application back, like `user_support_email`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<App_ID>?
        fields=name,description,creator_uid,user_support_email
        &access_token=<App_ID>|<App_Secret>
```

Comment: Super, this is a great start!

Comment: I found what I think might be the app secret and tried this technique, but I'm getting the response: "error": { "message": "Unsupported operation", "type": "FacebookApiException", "code": 100 }

Comment: Nevermind, we managed to get the credentials through a past employee. :)